# Library project activity not found error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, activitynotfoundexception

I am working on a project , where i need to render pdf on my device screen.

For that i am using **mupdf** library.

I have included it in my project.

Now from library project , i need to use **MuPDFActivity.class** through intent for showing pdf.

But i am getting **activitynotfound** exception.

I have tried of including library's activity in my manifest.

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.xrgpc.mupdf.MuPDFActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
```

But i am getting same error.
Will some one guide me what's i am doing wrong.

Comment: Is your library project included properly ?

Comment: the name should be: com.artifex.mupdf. Can you explain better? Did you included the source code in your project?

Answer (score 0):

check your library minSdk, if your library minSdk smaller then app you can not declaring at AndroidManifest.xml

And change if you import appcompat Activity to AppCompatActivity